# Get lists in list with names of possible multiple duplicate columns by values which can also include missing values

Tags: python, pandas

*This question is continuation: [Get lists in list with names of duplicate columns by values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61260149/get-lists-in-list-with-names-of-duplicate-columns-by-values) (answers in that question solves example but cannot handle several duplicates and missing values)*

I have data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#data = [[101, 1, 2, 10, 3, 2, 3, 1], [5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5], [30, 3, 7, 14, 10, 7, 10, 2], [11, 2, 6, 15, 20, 6, 20, 11]] 

#df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['xen', 'sim', 'tab', 'sim', 'simm', 'box', 'simm', 'res'])

data = [[np.nan, 1, 2, 10, 3, 2, 2, 3, 1, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "a", "a", "a", "a"], 
        [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "sd", "sd", "sd", "sd"], 
        [30, 3, 7, 14, 10, 7, 7, 10, 2, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "wrt", "wrt", "wrt", "wrt"], 
        [11, 2, 6, 15, 9, 6, 6, 9, 11, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, "r", "r", "r", "r"], 
        [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['xen', 'sim', 'tab', 'sim', 'simm', 'box', 'rex', 'simm', 'res', 'fen', 'zeb', 'zex', 'ser', 'ser', "asd", "bsd", "zar", "zar"])
```

That data frame (`df`) looks like:

```
|   xen |   sim |   tab |   sim |   simm |   box |   rex |   simm |   res |   fen |   zeb |   zex |   ser |   ser | asd   | bsd   | zar   | zar   |
|------:|------:|------:|------:|-------:|------:|------:|-------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|------:|:------|:------|:------|:------|
|   nan |     1 |     2 |    10 |      3 |     2 |     2 |      3 |     1 |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan | a     | a     | a     | a     |
|     5 |     5 |     5 |     5 |      5 |     5 |     5 |      5 |     5 |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan | sd    | sd    | sd    | sd    |
|    30 |     3 |     7 |    14 |     10 |     7 |     7 |     10 |     2 |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan | wrt   | wrt   | wrt   | wrt   |
|    11 |     2 |     6 |    15 |      9 |     6 |     6 |      9 |    11 |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan | r     | r     | r     | r     |
|   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |    nan |   nan |   nan |    nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan |   nan | nan   | nan   | nan   | nan   |
```

I need to get lists in list with names of duplicate columns (which can be any number) by values (it can be duplicate by name or may not) and can contain any number of missing values. For data frame above output should be like:

```
[["tab", "box", "rex"], ["simm", "simm"], ["fen", "zeb", "zex", "ser", "ser"], ["asd", "bsd", "zar", "zar"]]
```

Comment: Again, is there an actual issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC What you mean? Can you please specify?

Comment: What isn't clear? Do you have a **specific** problem or question?

Comment: @AMC I did not knew how to solve particular task. And I asked it. " I need to get lists in list with names of duplicate columns (which can be any number) by values (it can be duplicate by name or may not) and can contain any number of missing values." Maybe question is not formulated perfectly (sorry about my English) but it is specific question. And because my english may not be perfect I added coed, expected output, visual data representation. What is wrong with my question?

Comment: _I did not knew how to solve particular task._ That describes virtually every single question on here, it's nowhere near specific enough. _And I asked it._ That is the goal/objective, not the problem or obstacle.

Comment: @AMC Sorry but I do not agree with you. "get lists in list with names of duplicate columns" + particular conditions "(which can be any number) by values (it can be duplicate by name or may not) and can contain any number of missing values" I think is particular and very specific problem.

Comment: There is a difference between what you’re trying to do, and what is stopping you from reaching that goal. What **specifically** is stopping you from doing this? Which part are you struggling with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at this and see if it works for you:

```
#find duplicate rows
res = df.T.loc[df.T.duplicated(keep=False)]

#replace null values with string
#makes it easier later for grouping
res = res.fillna('empty').reset_index().astype(str)

#exclude the index column
cols = res.columns[1:].tolist()

res = res.set_index(cols)

#groupby index to get pairings
res.groupby(res.index).agg(list)['index'].tolist()

[['tab', 'box', 'rex'],
 ['simm', 'simm'],
 ['asd', 'bsd', 'zar', 'zar'],
 ['fen', 'zeb', 'zex', 'ser', 'ser']]
```

Comment: Aah, you beat me to it. Was about to post the same solution. Upvote.

Comment: @Ehsan Please post it if it even slightly different. It will be useful for learning different ways. Thank you.

Comment: @vasili111 Would have commented the diff but I used the same idea. Almost identical solution. Thank you.

Comment: @Ehsan Thank you for you effort :)

Answer (score 1):

From another question

```
df.T.fillna('nan').reset_index().groupby(df.index.tolist())['index'].agg(list).loc[lambda x : x.str.len()>=2].values.tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['tab', 'box', 'rex'], ['simm', 'simm'], ['asd', 'bsd', 'zar', 'zar'], ['fen', 'zeb', 'zex', 'ser', 'ser']]
```

Comment: When I see your code only thing I want to say is "WOW"!